# Can I use selenium webdriver on a non-gui server? (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web, firefox

I want to use the selenium webdriver on a linux server running Ubuntu. How can I use selenium on said server without opening a browser, as it doesn't have one? I'm using Selenium with Python and Gecko(Firefox), but I'll be willing to switch to JavaScript or Chrome if I have to.

Comment: Why don't try it?Although I don't try this in the past,but I think it could.

Comment: I'll try, but I might have problems with the driver